# Trigger an event when page is loaded with a unique id (anchor link)

Tags: javascript

I need a button to be triggered on page load. Which I've figured out how to do with a window.onload function.

But what I need to figure out is how to trigger this only when the page is loaded from a unique id (eg the button would be auto clicked when visited from example.com/#xyz , but not triggered when visited from example.com).

I don't know js much at all, so I'm not sure if this is even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an if statement!

```
if(location.hash === "#xyz") {
    /// Do stuff
}
```

There isn't an event for "when the URL hash becomes a specific value".  There are events for "page loaded" and for "url hash changed", and any check more specific than that needs to be handled by putting an `if` statement in one of those events.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty common to come across answers with javascript for a jquery question, because for simplicity sake. Since it is easily achieved using JavaScript.

```
var location = window.location.pathname; //returns /xyz/index.html
```

Please note that it is recommended not to use $(location) in jquery which may not provide an expected behaviour.

```
$(location).attr('pathname');
```

Please read this post [Get current URL with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-with-jquery) to get much clearer idea about JS and JQuery comparison for best practices.
I included the answer to keep it clear and link for more explanation.

Comment: I think you forgot that the `#` sign has special behavior in URLs.  URL hashes won't show up as part of the pathname.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. let me edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Oh, that isn't how it works either.  If the URL is "example.com/#xyz", then the pathname will simply be "/", because everything after the hash sign is moved into the `hash` variable rather than the `pathname` variable.  Also the index.html won't be added, since that's strictly a detail of how the server works, not a part of the URL.